# Passport Auth user update

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

i store an relation in the user model, but as soon as i save the authenticated user, a new login always response "Unauthenticated". This is the store method:

```
$this->authorize('create', Organization::class);
$organization = Organization::create($request->validated());
Auth::user()->organization()->associate($organization)->save();
```

This are the relation to the organization in the user-model:

```
public function organization(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Organization::class, 'organization_id');
}
```

and the relation in the organization-model to the user:

```
public function users(): HasMany
{
     return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Things like:

```
User::find(Auth::user()->getAuthIdentifier())->first()->update(['organization_id' => $organization->id]);
Auth::user()->forceFill(['organization' => $organization->id])->save()
```

brings the same effect.

I dump after save() the user with dd(Auth::user()) and i see in the changes array, that the password is in it. Maybe this is the problem, but i don't know, the hash is the same in the database before and after save.

Anybody an idea?

Cheers Ralf

Comment: Make sure the `password` field is in the `User` model's `$fillable` property if you're using mass assignment.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter It is. But i didn't change the password, i'm only change the organization_id